# Using Bootstrap, how do we make an app look like a smartphone app on bigger screen such as that of an iPhone 6?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap, an app I have will look like a smartphone app, even if I just resize my Google Chrome's window on the Mac to be very narrow.

However, I found that when I use iPhone 6 to open the app, it actually looks like a regular desktop app, with the text too small to see.

How can it be made to look like a smartphone app (without the simple layout) on iPhone 6?  (is it due to iPhone 6 having a bigger screen?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to your `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Or you can post your main html code.

More info: [Bootstrap Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Comment: oh it works... just wonder why it works on a desktop browser but not on the mobile phone... so it must be needing to tell the mobile's browser not to treat itself as a powerful browser, as your line is doing

Comment: Exactly. Think back to when the first iPhone was released. You had shitty blackberry experiences of using your little ball to move around pieces of the screen. This tag is like "lets take any existing site and let you see,  pinch to zoom (remember how impressive that shit was?!), or people who have optimized their sites can control how it looks. But by default, regular sites will be rendered as if the phone is 960px (the default width those days)